# Magento 2 Product Page HTTP 500 Error

Tags: magento2, error, http-error-500

First time posting here for Magento2, so if this is not correct method or place, please let me know how to rectify. Using version 2.1.0 currently.

Hitting http 500 error on product page URL in browser. All other pages of the Magento 2 install are loading fine and as they should. Developer mode turned back on and errors showing in browser as below:

```
2 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container does not exist
```

Have tried the solutions that suggest it's a cache issue. We have cleared the var/generation folder. Not a permissions issue, as all other pages loading fine and have set permissions to be as they need to be following those relevant guides.

Potential for one of the catalog database tables to be corrupt? Missing files?

Comment: have you checked the existence of : Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container or maybe it doesnt have correct permissions ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I'm looking in the correct location, but within /httpdocs/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Product/ area there is no folder called Item. Is this the correct location to be looking? i.e. the vendor folder?

Comment: Since when did you get this error ? After an upgrade ? Did you try to remove your `vendor/` directory and then `composer install` again ?

Comment: This is a fresh install, we've then imported client's products in. I can try updating to latest version if you think that will fix? Hesitant to try major things like the delete of a directory and then re-install as it took us around 20 hours to get the site to this stage. Stable. We are new to Magento2. Experienced in Magento1. I don't want to just guess and re-install everything until it works..... as this has resulted in the site completely breaking in the past and us having to start from scratch.

Comment: It sounds like you are missing files. If that file is actually missing, you should remove vendor/magento and update composer, then check if that file exists.

Comment: I went to Magento 2.1.0 repository on GitHub to see if the class 'Container' does exist and it doesn't but its added in the newer Magento 2.1.* versions. So my suggestion is removing ```vendor/``` directory and calling ```composer install``` command or updating your Magento 2 installation  with ```composer update```. My preference is updating Magento 2.1  because you will have newest version and it will be more secure.

Comment: Tried both composer install and composer update commands through 2 separate attempts, and long story short, no change. Any other ideas on how to rectify? The block type being referenced is still missing...... is this a theme issue perhaps in that it is referencing a file that doesn't exist in this Magento version? Still on Magento version 2.1.0 as it stands. And still in developer mode.

Comment: Please help, I'm faced with a similar issue; When I open my magento homepage it loads successfully while catalog search, categories, product page and other pages load a http 500 error. Initially it was only the product page that loads a http 500 error, but after running the following command php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush all other pages were affected only the homepage exempted. Please assist on what I could do to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still no fix for this, but it looks like it is a theme issue. In that the theme code is not working with current version of Magento.

Comment: Just to confirm issue fixed by convincing the theme developer it was an issue with his theme not being compatible with current version of Magento. He corrected his code for product page, and we've updated to latest version of Magento 2.1.5 and all is now working fine. Hoping some of the above can help others debug a similar issue though. Some of the answers might be valid.

Answer (score 2):

Check for `var` Module permission.

First run

```
php bin/magento list
```

Above one gives u where the error is & check error logs in `var` folder.

If above things not work, then follow below ones

Go to `magento\vendor`

Delete All Files.

Go to command line to ur Magento Root Path

Run `composer install`

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Entire staging area now giving http 500 error on every page...... back to square one again....... this is really what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: Have managed to get frontend back up...... but product page now has http 500 error and developer mode error is not showing any longer.

Comment: After login for admin area, instead of being redirected to dashboard, we see error below now: 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/etc/pki/tls/certs) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/gamefishltd.co.uk/:/tmp/) in /var/www/vhosts/gamefishltd.co.uk/httpdocs/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Util/RemoteFilesystem.php on line 914

Comment: Fixing that error then generates another error: 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException): File "/var/www/vhosts/gamefishltd.co.uk/httpdocs/pub/static/_requirejs/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs-config.js" cannot be opened Warning!fopen(/var/www/vhosts/gamefishltd.co.uk/httpdocs/pub/static/_requirejs/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/requirejs-config.js): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Comment: I've now managed to reproduce the error on the product page in browser - 2 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid block type: Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container
Exception #1 (ReflectionException): Class Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Item\Container does not exist

Comment: So after 3 hours of running commands and working through errors and solutions for them from other posts, I'm now exactly back where I started.....

Comment: U r still stuck @PrimalSpace?

Comment: Very much so. Right back to where we started. Everything on the site is loading fine, apart from the product page giving the same error as above in browser. Have contacted theme developer to check code for product page is as it should be. Potential there for it not being compatible with latest version of composer and Magento 2.1.0, any other ideas for fixing?

Comment: Just deactivate the Theme first & Check with Luma Default Theme. Using own Attribute Set of Default for Products? All product having issue or some of them? Can chat on Magento as well

Comment: just as a site note: if use the magento shell commands (e.g. `php bin/magento cache:flush`) then always remember to do this as the webserver-user/magento-file-owner, not as root or some other user, because magento will then create files with the wrong owner permissions. In most cases you should do this as www-data, but usually www-data has no shell access. Then you should (if you are logged in as root) use `sudo -u www-data php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy <locale_LOCALE>`. The static files will then have www-data:www-data as owner:group instead of root:root or whatever

Answer (score 0):

Please check your css/js files path by viewing the source code. If they are not accessible because of some version number in their path then you may try running the following mysql query:

```
INSERT INTO `core_config_data` (`scope`, `scope_id`, `path`, `value`) VALUES ('default', 0, 'dev/static/sign', '0');
```

Source: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/7869